# ModuleNotFoundError in build with pyproject.toml

Tags: python, build, pyproject.toml

So I'm working on a package, i did some builds and while changing things suddenly it doesn't build anymore, neither on my machine nor on azure devops. It seems to not install dependencies during the build because it fails at the topmost import (can tell form changing the import order).
Using build with python -m build with pyproject.toml
This is the pyproject.toml:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61", "pyodbc"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "module"
description = "..."
authors = [
    { ... },
]

classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]
dependencies = [
    'docx',    
    'click',
    'click_spinner',
    'dynaconf',
    'pandas',
    'pyarrow',
    'pyodbc',
    'sqlalchemy',
    'docxtpl'

]

dynamic = ["version"]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["module"]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
module = ["assets/*.jpg", "assets/*.csv", "assets/*.docx"]


[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "..."

[project.scripts]
module = "module.main:cli"

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = { attr = "module.__version__" }
```

then i get this error:

```
    import click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered on a different platform (man stackoverflow is done for, crazy ...)

The error message is misleading I think, the issue was this line in the pyproject.toml:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = { attr = "module.__version__" }
```

In my case, I have **version** in version.py instead of **init**.py to avoid circular imports, so I needed to change the versioning like this:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = { attr = "module.version.__version__" }
```

aaand that was it! No idea why it broke at external import statements not at version imports.